# Magmi import error - SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect integer value

Tags: magmi

When I try to import products via magmi I got this error

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect integer value: 'No' for column 'value' at row 2 -
```

Can I know what should I check?

magmi 0.7.21 Magento 1.8.1 group product

```
sku attribute_set   type    grouped_skus    website _product_websites   amxnotif_hide_alert card_artist card_color  card_converted_mana_cost    card_expansion  card_format card_loyalty    card_name_english   card_name_en    card_number card_power  card_rarity card_finish card_toughness  image   image_label language    name    price   short_description   small_image small_image_label   thumbnail   thumbnail_label _media_image    _media_lable    status  tax_class_id    visibility  weight  qty use_config_min_qty  use_config_min_sale_qty use_config_max_sale_qty is_in_stock use_config_notify_stock_qty use_config_manage_stock use_config_qty_increments   use_config_enable_qty_inc   _media_attribute_id
Single-DTK-E-132-001    Card    grouped Single-DTK-S-E-132-001  LetsPlayFirst   base    No  Cliff Childs    Colorless   6   Dragons of Tarkir           Scion of Ugin   S   1   4   Uncommon    Normal  4   /MTG/132-DTK/EN/DTK-EN-001.png  Scion of Ugin English Dragons of Tarkir English Scion of Ugin   0   Scion of Ugin   /MTG/132-DTK/EN/DTK-EN-001.png  Scion of Ugin English Dragons of Tarkir /MTG/132-DTK/EN/DTK-EN-001.png  Scion of Ugin English Dragons of Tarkir /MTG/132-DTK/EN/DTK-EN-001.png  Scion of Ugin English Dragons of Tarkir 1   None    4   0   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
```

Comment: Show your CSV input file.

Comment: @Axel I update some csv input line and data as example Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The error states you're trying to import a string based value `No` into a field that only accepts integer values (numbers).

Try changing your `No` value in the CSV to `0`.

No should be `0`
Yes should be `1`